# C4267: 'return' : conversion from 'size_t' to 'const UINT', possible loss of data

Tags: c++, casting

How to resolve below warning using typecast to const UINT?

C4267: 'return' : conversion from 'size_t' to 'const UINT', possible loss of data

```
Class CManager
{
   std::vector<CString>    m_ncount;
   public:
    const UINT GetMCount( int nInst) const;
}


const UINT CManager::GetMCount( int nInst) const
{
     return m_ncount.size();//C4267
}
```

Is this correct?:

```
const UINT CManager::GetMCount( int nInst) const
{
     return (const UINT)m_ncount.size();//C4267
}
```

Comment: And why not return size_t?

Comment: `size_t` is guaranteed to represent the size of any object in C++, whereas `UINT` cannot. Return `size_t` instead.

Comment: There's no reason to return a `const UINT`. Just return a `UINT` (or better yet, a `std::size_t`).

Answer (score 3):

`UINT` (which is not standard. `unsigned int` is the standard one actually) is at least 16 bit which means it is implementation dependable. No guarantees that it would work as an `index` or container `size`. However, `size_t` size is, by definition, exactly as output of `sizeof` operator. Which is guaranteed to work in all cases on all platforms.

So, the solution is to use `size_t`. Any other solution will be working around with ignoring the actual problem. Be thankful for your compiler warning!

Answer (score 1):

If you might need to hold more than `INT_MAX` items in your vector, use `size_t`. In most cases, it doesn't really matter, but I use `size_t` just to remove the warning.

Just try this one

```
std::size_t CManager::GetMCount( int nInst) const
{
     return m_ncount.size();
}
```

Comment: Do you want to mean `auto CManager::GetMCount( int nInst) const -> decltype(m_ncount.size()) { return m_ncount.size();} ` ? And there is no need to return a const value, it is passed by value

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `UINT` then you are coding probably under windows. In 32bit applications `sizeof(UINT)` and `sizeof(size_t)` are equal to 4, but under 64bit builds this is not true, `sizeof(UINT)` is 4 but `sizeof(size_t)` is 8.

One solution is to use `UINT_PTR`, also whatever type you will stay with add static assertion, ex:

```
static_assert(sizeof(UINT_PTR) == sizeof(size_t), "size_t must equal to ULONG_PTR");
```

If you are not bound to windows platform and its specific type macro definitions, then consider returning `size_t`.